# Download file using wget from particular address

Tags: linux, terminal, download, wget, curl

I want to download this file from "http://dl.ariamovie.host/dl5/user2/amir3/Serial/iZombie/S01/480p/iZombie%20S01%20E01.480p.AriaMovie.mkv" using wget or curl.

```
I tried using:
wget -c "http://dl.ariamovie.host/dl5/user2/amir3/Serial/iZombie/S01/480p/iZombie%20S01%20E01.480p.AriaMovie.mkv"
```

But got this as output

```
    --2019-05-18 09:06:30--  http://dl.ariamovie.host/dl5/user2/amir3/Serial/iZombie/S01/480p/iZombie%20S01%20E01.480p.AriaMovie.mkv
Resolving dl.ariamovie.host (dl.ariamovie.host)... 104.27.165.97, 104.27.164.97, 2606:4700:30::681b:a461, ...
Connecting to dl.ariamovie.host (dl.ariamovie.host)|104.27.165.97|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://srv1.uploadsara.net/dl5/user2/amir3/Serial/iZombie/S01/480p/iZombie%20S01%20E01.480p.AriaMovie.mkv [following]
--2019-05-18 09:06:30--  http://srv1.uploadsara.net/dl5/user2/amir3/Serial/iZombie/S01/480p/iZombie%20S01%20E01.480p.AriaMovie.mkv
Resolving srv1.uploadsara.net (srv1.uploadsara.net)... 185.191.78.26
Connecting to srv1.uploadsara.net (srv1.uploadsara.net)|185.191.78.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2019-05-18 09:08:43--  (try: 2)  http://srv1.uploadsara.net/dl5/user2/amir3/Serial/iZombie/S01/480p/iZombie%20S01%20E01.480p.AriaMovie.mkv
Connecting to srv1.uploadsara.net (srv1.uploadsara.net)|185.191.78.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2019-05-18 09:10:55--  (try: 3)  http://srv1.uploadsara.net/dl5/user2/amir3/Serial/iZombie/S01/480p/iZombie%20S01%20E01.480p.AriaMovie.mkv
Connecting to srv1.uploadsara.net (srv1.uploadsara.net)|185.191.78.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

PS: 
**I wanted to run this on a google colab, so as to download multiple files from a given index.**

***If this is not possible by wget then any other software usage, until it is command line, is also welcome.***

Comment: Your wget command worked fine for me !  (At least the content started downloading) I wonder if it was a fault in the cluster serving it, or some kind of limit you were hitting and the server was denying you?

Comment: Please try this on a google colab environment, as I am using it there. The command for colab, what I am using is  **!wget -c "http://dl.ariamovie.host/dl5/user2/amir3/Serial/iZombie/S01/480p/iZombie%20S01%20E01.480p.AriaMovie.mkv"**